# How to handle user gesture required is required error from browsers

Tags: asp.net-core, printing

Hello I'm using [neodynamic weblientprint](https://www.neodynamic.com/Products/Help/WebClientPrint6.0/articles/getting-started.html)  to print directly from browser. There's a part that includes a script that detects if the client utility is installed, after which its retrives the printers installed on the system.

However I intermittently get this error when the script runs - Unable to launch 'webclientprintvi: -getPrinters:  because a user gesture is required.

I get this error on some client system browsers, while some client systems browsers never show this error. Is there a setting that needs to be configured on the browser. Browsers tests are chrome and edge

Thanks.

Comment: If you call this check only as response to the action of a user (say, you do it in a button click handler), it should always work. You are just not supposed to do it automatically without the user asking for it.

Comment: Please check the [The client machine requirements](https://www.neodynamic.com/Products/Help/WebClientPrint6.0/articles/wcpp.html), perhaps the issue is related to the browser version.  For windows clients: BROWSER: Internet Explorer 6 or greater (IE10/11 in Desktop Mode), Microsoft Edge, Mozilla Firefox 2.0 or greater, Google Chrome 11 or greater, Opera 9.0 or greater, Safari 3.0 or greater.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that if you are using the WCPP detection feature, then calling jsWebClientPrint.getPrinters() will produce the "...because a user gesture is required" console error.  I had a page that called that method w/o the detection and it worked w/o complaining.

I didn't dive any deeper than that as to determining why the extra embedding detection causes this to happen.  I just re-worked the page, calling the method instead on a Refresh button click; which, of course Chrome is then happen with.